# Spacing in name abbreviations

Tags: abbreviations

Should the boy's name C.J. be abbreviated this way, as C. J. with a space, or as CJ without periods or spaces? I'm sure this is somewhere in the Chicago Manual of Style, but don't see it mentioned explicitly in 7.66, 8.4, or 10.12 which is where I'd think it would be located.